# Qt and QDateTime comparing

Tags: c++, qt

i have a trouble with qt qdatetime comparing

```
if(now.secsTo(nearest)>0)
```

always shows the same number.

```
QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime nearest = QDateTime::fromString(ui.timetableTable->item(0,2)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString(),"dd.MM.yy HH:mm");
```

how can i can i get the right result of comparing two dates. Thanks for help!

Comment: The approach is right. Does the `nearest` hold the correct value as in the time table after `QDateTime::fromString()`??

Comment: how can i check it? if i display it in a message box, it shows up correctly.

Comment: Can you add an example value for `ui.timetableTable->item(0,2)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString()` to your question and what do you mean by **always shows the same number**??. The QDateTime::secsTo()` will give you a valid result if `now` and `nearest` are valid.

Comment: i have QTableWidget filled out with dates. i get date from there with QDateTime::fromString. then i use secsTo() and watch result from QmessageBox where i can only see 11347... every time exact same number (sorry for my english, im not native speaker)

Comment: Can you provide here the value of item(0,2) in your table widget. And is the entry in your table widget dependent on the current time by any chance.  That is the only possibility that you get a constant value. Unless you are not calling the `QDateTime::currentdateTime()` before every time you call `secTo()` or your `fromString()` format doesn't match.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/oeFWXzDyhwxoe that's the my table. the table fills manually

Comment: The `nearest`  got using `QDateTime::fromString` and year format `"yy"` will store a default year of 1900 , so in your table example 1915. You can Change it to some thing like this  `nearest =nearest.addYears(100);`

Comment: Thanks, a lot! it works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When using `QDateTime::fromString()`,Default values are assigned to any field that is not provided in the format string. The default values are provided [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#fromString-2).
2. In your case while passing `"yy"` as a year format, the default value for the year is 1900 + the value passed in the field of `"yy"`. 
   Example:

   ```
    QDateTime nearest = QDateTime::fromString("02.07.15 12:15","dd.MM.yy
    HH:mm");    
    qDebug()<< nearest; //Will give: QDateTime("1915-07-02 12:15:00.000)
   ```
3. You can modify the default value using `QDateTime::addYears()`. For the above example:

   ```
    nearest = nearest.addYears(100);
   ```