# Qt and QdateTime comparing

Tags: c++, qt

i have a trouble with qt qdatetime comparing

```
if(now.secsTo(nearest)>0)
```

always shows the same number.

```
QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime nearest = QDateTime::fromString(ui.timetableTable->item(0,2)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString(),"dd.MM.yy HH:mm");
```

how can i can i get the right result of comparing two dates. Thanks for help!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что this question belongs on Stack Overflow in English.

Comment: У нас тут вопросы по-русски задают, будьте добры переведите свой вопрос, в противном случае его закроют.

Comment: `always shows the same number` which is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt and QDateTime comparing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499638/qt-and-qdatetime-comparing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the objects are compared in different formats.
Replace "dd.MM.yy HH: mm" to "dd.MM.yyyy HH: mm" and will get you Happiness. it turns out that Qt compares 1915 and 2015.

```
QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime nearest = QDateTime::fromString("26.07.2015 15:35","dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
qDebug() << now.toString("dd.MM.yy HH:mm") << nearest.toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm") << now.secsTo(nearest);
```

Outputs

- "24.07.15 20:35" "26.07.2015 15:35" 154775
- "24.07.15 20:35" "26.07.2015 15:35" 154762

Around Your Code

```
 QDateTime nearest = QDateTime::fromString("26.07.15 15:35","dd.MM.yy HH:mm");
qDebug() << now.toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm") << nearest.toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm") << now.secsTo(nearest);
```

- "24.07.2015 20:47" "26.07.1915 15:35" -3155602364